# Using AWS Redshift for building a Multi-tenant SaaS application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We're building a multi-tenant SaaS application hosted on AWS that exposes and visualizes data in the front end via a REST api.

Now, for storage we're considering using `AWS Redshift` (Cluster or Serverless?) and then exposing the data using `API Gateway` and `Lambda` with the Redshift Data API.

The reason why I'm inclined to using `Redshift` as opposed to e.g `RDS` is that it seems like a nice option to also be able to conduct data experiments internally when building our product.

My question is, would this be considered a good strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift is sized for very large data and tables.  For example the minimum storage size is 1MB. That's 1MB for every column and across all the slices (minimum 2).  A table with 5 columns and just a few rows will take 26MB on the smallest Redshift cluster size (default distribution style).  Redshift shines when your tables have 10s of millions of rows minimum.  It isn't clear from your case that you will have the data sizes that will run efficiently on Redshift.

The next concern would be about your workload.  Redshift is a powerful analytics engine but is not designed for OLTP workloads.  High volumes of small writes will not perform well; it wants batch writes.  High concurrency of light reads will not work as well as a database designed for that workload.

At low levels of work Redshift can do these things - it is a database.  But if you use it in a way it isn't optimized for it likely isn't the most cost effective option and won't scale well.  If job A is the SAS workload and analytics is job B, then choose the right database for job A.  If this choice cannot do job B at the performance level you need then add an analytics engine to the mix.

My $.02 and I'm the Redshift guy.  If my assumptions about your workload are wrong please update with specific info.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Definitely w.r.t workload our case is *very* light (not even in the millions of rows).

The transactional workload will not be high since it's gonna be a daily dump. The number of concurrent light reads might be, though..

The thing that inclined me to Redshift was the fact that we need to do queries for which the structure of the incoming data is not very well suited. So I was encouraged by the idea that I could do some scheduled transformations to the data inside Redshift that made the queries easier

Comment: There is no doubt that Redshift has significant data processing horsepower but some of that is based on how it organizes the data on disk and this is in part based on the large "block" size.   I'd think that a postgres RDS instance would, on balance, perform better in this case.  But if you need the high performance read-based analytics of Redshift then you can likely work around some of the Redshift low spots.